# How to link to a library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010.

My library is in a folder called "lib" which is in the project folder.

I had added the library to `Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Directories`, and have tried various things in `Properties>Linker>General>Additional Library` Directories but none work (have tried ../lib, $(SolutionDir)../lib, lib, and same with an additional slash at the end).

I also tried just having it in the project folder which didn't work either. (With $(SolutionDir) in Additional Library Directories or blank)

I always get this linker error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cyclone_d.lib'` or     `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cyclone.lib' if trying to build a release version.`

If anybody has any ideas about what I need to do that would be fantastic.

Comment: Is there a 64 vs 32 bit mismatch between the DLL binaries and the target binary that you're trying to build?

Comment: You need to add the library to Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies.

Comment: It is just a "file not found" error message, very common of course.  Notable is that you never told us where you actually put these .lib files.  It matters.

Comment: cup - sorry I meant additional dependencies not additional directories. They are there. Hans - the .lib is in the "lib" folder in my project folder like I said. Or did you mean something else? torak - how do I check that? I'm not sure :-/